# MVC routing priority for shared views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

My solution has shared views with similar names in different folder locations

```
~\Views\Shared\Discount.ascx
~\Views\Dashboard\Shared\Discount.ascx
```

I'm extending **WebFormViewEngine** to define a view engine for routing

```
public class AreaViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public AreaViewEngine() : base()
    {
        ViewLocationFormats = new[] {
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Views/Dashboard/Shared/{0}.ascx"
        };

        MasterLocationFormats = new[] {
            "~/Shared/{0}.master"
        };

        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
    }
}
```

This is causing issues for views with similar names. I want to set higher priority to **~/Views/Dashboard/Shared/{0}.ascx** if the URL contains **/Dashboard/**

Anyone knows how to do it? or is aware of a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score -1):

You could override the FindView method in your custom ViewEngine class, and look for a match containing the URL fragment before falling back to the default behavior.

```
public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
{
    var fragment = ... // access URL via controllerContext
    var preferred = ViewLocationFormats.Where(x => x.Contains(fragment)).ToList();
    // return retult from preferred or fall back to base.FindView
}
```

I'm not a big fan of this approach, though. If you need a view to be "overridable", you could simply make its output conditional or dependent upon model values, such as by adding a DiscountView property to your view model and then using the value of this property to decide what your view should emit.

If all you desire is "clever naming clash handling" then I'd recommend using T4MVC instead. It allows you to reference your views specifically and without magic strings, resolving any ambiguities that multiple views of the same name might otherwise cause.

Comment: Not sure how to "return result from preferred", but falling back to base.FindView seems to be using the Formats set in the beginning.